# PHP LimitIterator fails ("Does not support seeking" + "Cannot rewind file")

Tags: php, spl, splfileobject

I use `SplFileObject` and `LimitIterator` to read content from position x till y of a big file.

This works perfectly when using a file path like `/home/devel/stuff/myfile.log`.

When using a path like `http://mydomain.com:8090/devel/stuff/myfile.log` it does not work. The path is correct however.

Does this fail when using absolute paths?

---

The error messages are:

`PHP Warning:  SplFileObject::rewind() [<a href='splfileobject.rewind'>splfileobject.rewind</a>]: stream does not support seeking in ...`

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Cannot rewind file ...'`

---

Full code:

```
  // $pStrFile contains the valid (yes!) path
  $oFile = new SplFileObject($pStrFile);
  // $nFrom = 80 and $nLines = 30
  $fileIterator = new LimitIterator($oFile, $nFrom, $nLines);

  foreach($fileIterator as $line) {
      $strLines .= $line;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of the http wrapper. If a file is on the disk, you can access it on any position. If you want to start reading in the middle of the file, that is possible. However, when the file is on a webserver and you get it with HTTP, it is a little bit harder to read the middle of the file.

You can [copy](http://php.net/copy) the file to a temporary location and then use the LimitIterator on it.

Comment: Well it is not what I was looking for but it is a solution that currently works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To have the `rewind()` function work on [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/splfileobject), the underlying streamwrapper needs to support seeking.

PHPs current [HTTP stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) does not support seeking. So you get the error message:

> PHP Warning: SplFileObject::rewind() [splfileobject.rewind]: stream does not support seeking in ...

A first idea that came into my mind was to use the [`NoRewindIterator`](http://php.net/NoRewindIterator) that just disables the `rewind()` call and therefore prevents triggering the error.

```
$obj      = new SplFileObject('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
$norewind = new NoRewindIterator($obj);
$limit    = new LimitIterator($norewind, 80, 30);
```

However, as there is no `rewind()` any longer, the [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/LimitIterator) is somewhat fooled, too. That results in ignoring the *offset* parameter, it would not be the offset of 80 but just of zero (no offset).

To overcome this, a [`CachingIterator`](http://php.net/CachingIterator) can be inserted into the mix. It solves exactly that problem:

```
$obj      = new SplFileObject('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
$norewind = new NoRewindIterator($obj);
$caching  = new CachingIterator($norewind);
$limit    = new LimitIterator($caching, 80, 30);

foreach ($limit as $i => $line)
{
    printf("%03d: %s", $i, $line);
 }
```

Example output ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/M8w9nW)):

```
080: 
081: </span>
082:                 </div>
083:                 <div id="hsearch">
084:                     <form id="search" action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off">
085:                     <div>
```

As you can see, technically PHPs SPL ships with enough internal tools to spare writing to a temporary file for the HTTP stream. But please keep in mind, that the iterator here is forward only, meaning that you only can use it once.