# How to read a value from 'x'th row and 'y'th column in CSV using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I am wondering whether it is possible to read a specific value from CSV specifed the row number and column number.

Lets say I want to read data from row number `44` and column number `K`?

I dont want to parse through the complete CSV. How to read specific data?

Hope I am clear with my question? Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question does not lack much of clarity. But it lacks of the code what you've done so far. The research.

Comment: I ve done the code to read from CSV. But all my research leads me to the way of parsing line by line from CSV until we reach the point. I am looking for a way where you can simply read the required data on a stroke.

Comment: You can't, the CSV file has no index so you can just move to the binary position inside the file where the line you want parse starts. If you use the `SplFileObject` however, you can benefit from buffered reading.

Comment: @hakre Thanks. Can you elaborate a bit more with working example.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV files have no index, so you would need at least to go to the 44th line and retrieve it:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($path);
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$single = new LimitIterator($file, $offset = 43, $limit = 1);
list($row) = iterator_to_array($single, false);
$k = 10;
echo $row[$k];
```

Comment: somehow I am facing this error.
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to LimitIterator::__construct() must implement interface Iterator, integer given in F:\Source - WebAutomation\reuters\test.php on line 4

Comment: Thanks. Lets say suppose I want 59th row also, should i __construt 'LimitIterator' once again with different offset?

Comment: No then I would first wrap `$file` in a `NoRewindIterator` then offset at 43 and then offset at 15 so to move from line 44 to 59. You might run into an unwanted side-effect when doing so (wrong lines, e.g. starting from the beginning again), in case you do, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13828745/367456 for details (but you probably do not).

Comment: Then what would be the best way if I dont want to run into any side effect?

Comment: If you run into side-effects you will notice. You probably don't in this case if it works for you. Only if the relative limiting is too far of, you might need to add a caching iterator in the middle. Don't get confused by that, you normally do not need that, just wanted to leave a link in case a future user does on a remote file or something.

Answer (score -1):

```
Here is a function that accepts the path to a CSV file, and inserts all records to the given MySQL table, paying attention to the column names: 

<?php 
function csv_file_to_mysql_table($source_file, $target_table, $max_line_length=10000) { 
    if (($handle = fopen("$source_file", "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ","); 
        foreach ($columns as &$column) { 
            $column = str_replace(".","",$column); 
        } 
        $insert_query_prefix = "INSERT INTO $target_table (".join(",",$columns).")\nVALUES"; 
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
            while (count($data)<count($columns)) 
                array_push($data, NULL); 
            $query = "$insert_query_prefix (".join(",",quote_all_array($data)).");"; 
            mysql_query($query); 
        } 
        fclose($handle); 
    } 
} 

function quote_all_array($values) { 
    foreach ($values as $key=>$value) 
        if (is_array($value)) 
            $values[$key] = quote_all_array($value); 
        else 
            $values[$key] = quote_all($value); 
    return $values; 
} 

function quote_all($value) { 
    if (is_null($value)) 
        return "NULL"; 

    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'"; 
    return $value; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: What does this vague answer really mean? I just want to read data from 'x'th row and 'y'th column. Is your answer relevent?